# How can i solve Geojson to shapefile conversion error?

Tags: node.js, geojson, shapefile, ogr

I'm trying to convert geojson file to shapefile. I'm using the geojson2shape method but when I run code below I receive this error. I also install ogr2ogr via npm install ogr2ogr but I have the error. How can I solve this error?

```
var geojson2shape = require('geojson2shape')
// a shapefile is actually multiple files. geojson2shape will output a zipped version if specified.
var zip = true
geojson2shape(__dirname+'/polygon.geojson', __dirname+'/polygon.shp',zip, function(err){
  if(err) throw err

  console.log('success');

})
```

```
Command failed: ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:\upload2/output/out.shp C:\upload2/Files/imgUploader_1577252750283_AC127138-5645-497D-AF51-3F4EA12E20C5.geojson -overwrite -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
'ogr2ogr' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Answer (score 0):

ogr2ogr is a "native application". The package in [npm called ogr2ggr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ogr2ogr) is just a kind of wrapper around the native tool, as it explains in the doc:

> ogr2ogr requires the command line tool ogr2ogr - gdal install page. We recommended using the latest stable version.

So to use `geojson2shape` or even npm's `ogr2ogr` [follow the instructions](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries) for installing gdal/ogr2ogr in your system, and make sure that `ogr2ogr` binary is on the `PATH`